# Install Java Package

Tags: java, installation, freebsd

I need to install Oracle JDK on FreeBSD 9.1.

I have install FreeBSD 9.1 with no ports attached into it.

So I downloaded **jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz** from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Now I just have no idea how to install and make it work on my FreeBSD.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to add the ports sources to your system, you can install from binary packages.

Java on FreeBSD is the OpenJDK implementation, for Java7, the command should be

```
pkg_add -r openjdk
```

While for Java6, it is:

```
pkg_add -r openjdk6
```

Due to redistribution restrictions, it isn't possible to use 'pkg_add -r' to install the linux distribution of Oracle JDK.  Also, the linux emulation is only 32-bit.  So, the *java/linux-sun-jdk17* port would use "jdk-7u25-linux-i586.tar.gz".

Comment: But before you need to create directory `/usr/ports` and then use `portsnap fetch` to update the repository. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ports.

The [recommended](http://www.freebsd.org/java/) Java implementation is [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) in `/usr/ports/java/openjdk7`.

You can use the Linux implementation of Sun's (now Oracle) java with 
`/usr/ports/java/linux-sun-jdk17`. Note that this has some legal restrictions, see the port Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Build your own - it's trivial to build OpenJDK from source these days - see https://java.net/projects/adoptopenjdk/ for details (Full Disclosure: I'm an admin on that project).